# Is it alright to use multiple backend frameworks with one database in a virtual machine

Tags: django, nginx, fastapi

I'm wondering if I could use multiple backend frameworks, using only 1 database in a VM instance in production without any problems. For example, I wanna keep Django Admin and its authentication rest API services, while using FastAPI for other things, possibly even ExpressJs in the future.

I want to achieve this because different frameworks have different strengths and available third-party libraries in their ecosystems.

I know NGINX as a reverse proxy and a load balancer will control the traffic load and directions to different endpoints. Still, would there be any conflicts in the database or anything I should be watching out for?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dedicated path and mount it on app init. It works with `flask`, so I guess `django` should work as well

Here's an example taken from the docs

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.wsgi import WSGIMiddleware
from flask import Flask, escape, request

flask_app = Flask(__name__)


@flask_app.route("/")
def flask_main():
    name = request.args.get("name", "World")
    return f"Hello, {escape(name)} from Flask!"


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/v2")
def read_main():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


app.mount("/v1", WSGIMiddleware(flask_app))
```

See the documentation at https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/wsgi/